# Why do some AJAX calls take drastically longer to finish than others when the URLs have the same response time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

To simplify my situation; I have 3 PHP pages. Two of them adds and removes rows from a database, respectively. The third fetches all of the rows, encodes them as JSON and prints the result.

I have timed the execution of all the pages, which ranges from 0.001 to 0.004 seconds. Here are the timings of the Ajax calls however:

Fetch entire table as JSON: 8-12ms
Add row: 990-1010ms
Remove row: 990-1010ms

The response time of the add and remove times are causing unnecessary sluggishness in my application, considering the PHP execution times are mere fractions of seconds, and their output is simply "1" for success and "0" for failure (Compared to the fetch call, which prints out up to 100 rows (~10 columns) of data as JSON)

All my Ajax return timings are measured in Firebug. All Ajax calls are made through jQuery (`$.ajax()`).

I'm guessing this has something to do with Firefox not considering a GET request answered unless it has received a particular amount of bytes or characters, and the 1 second response time being a timeout of some sort.

Any wisdom to share on the issue?

---

I've timed the AJAX loading times in Chrome and Opera as well (Averages):

Opera:
 * All AJAX calls ~15 ms

Chrome:
 * Remove row and fetch rows: ~25ms
 * Add row: ~350ms

My application is snappy and responsive in Opera, but sluggish to a varying degree in all other browsers. Exactly why is still unclear to me.

---

I've timed IE 9 as well, which performs practically identically to Opera. My application now operates swiftly in two browsers.

Comment: Can you post the code (PHP, HTML, JavaScript and MySQL)? And how big the database is? (# of rows)

Comment: Ryan Doherty: I'm afraid I can't, this being a proprietary project. I did already summarize the PHP execution timings in the question though, which includes MySQL queries and excludes PHP as the cause of the 1 second delay.

Any particular snippets of code you'd like to see I'm sure I could provide though

Comment: Have you tried measuring the loading time of each page when requested directly, and not via ajax? PHP has some overhead before your script is executed (more so if you're using some kind of framework).

Comment: Yes, please offer any code you can give us. Reduce the HTML, JS and SQL to just the bare minimum and change the column names. You won't get any good answers without more information.

Comment: @Codemonkey, have you tried adding timing code the scripts themselves and seeing if there is a difference in the ajax calls and the direct calls? This could help narrow the issue down to yours/jquery ajax implementation for this specific task or possibly web server configurations holding open connections.

Comment: @Codemonkey, it's also worth mentioning you'd be better off using Chrome for getting close and personal with your ajax calls as abstracts network communications away from the OS allow for much more indepth information to gathered. Chrome's modified webkit inspector is invaluable for this kind of thing.

Comment: xzyfer: I've timed Chrome and Opera as well

Comment: Sorry, you're just not giving enough information for anyone to really be able to help you. It might be worth using trying with the latest build of jquery, or falling back to native xhr request to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently some browsers experience mysterious side effects from using `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1` in the URL. The added full second of delay was one of them. Using `127.0.0.1` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Could it still be a DNS problem if it acts differently in most every browser?

Comment: It's less likely, but still possible since the browsers implement their own DNS cache and things like that (I'm just saying that the browsers do *not* simply use the system's `gethostbyname()`)

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you use `HTTPWatch`.It will tell you the exact time of all js file and css and page rendering etc. in this way you can analyze, which call is taking more time and why.i am not sure that i answered your question or not, but hoping you might get some help from `HTTPWatch`.

**[Here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)** you have a good article which will tell you, how to improve site performance by minimizing request time.

Answer (score -1):

I have no information to base this on, but my guess right now is one of these culprits:

- Slow disk(s) - adding and deleting rows might require more disk access than reads (plus MySQL might be doing query caching)
- Indexes - MySQL has to update it's indexes when a column is changed or added

Barring that you should profile your code. Use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and/or run your MySQL queries directly via MySQL to see how long they take.

Comment: In my question I exclude MySQL or PHP as the cause of the delay. It has to be caused by Apache or Firefox.

Comment: How do you exclude them? Did you test your queries individually? Did you profile your PHP? Did you run the AJAX calls without querying the database?

Comment: I simply timed the PHP execution for each of the pages from start to finish

Comment: Ok then, you don't really know where the real issue is. Run xdebug and view how long each function call takes, that should help narrow it down. Also test each mysql insert and delete query individually.

Comment: Ok: If the total PHP execution time on all the pages is below 0.01 seconds, why would you think the problem lies there? The problem obviously has something to do with the browser, especially now since I've confirmed that Opera and IE runs the application just like you'd expect.

Comment: Interesting, I guess your information at first wasn't very clear. I see now you added timing for other browsers. And that you answered your own question. We couldn't see any of your code so we wouldn't have known you were using localhost.